# UML State Machine substate transition

Tags: uml, modeling

Is it possible in the UML to model transition from an outer state to an sub-state of a composiste-state like in the following figure (State3->State1.2)?

If so what is the semantics?

I guess When event occurs in State3

- the State3 Exit Action is executed
- the State1 Entry Action is executed
- the State1.2 Entry Action is executed

am I right?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. From the superstructure:

> Explicit entry: If the transition goes to a substate of the composite state, then that substate becomes active and its entry code is executed after the execution of the entry code of the composite state. This rule applies recursively if the transition terminates on a transitively nested substate.

Comment: Ok, but what does that _mean_?